# Can data be written or accessed outside of the directory tree?

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, filesystems

If I remember correctly, folders are essentially just files that point to locations where other files are stored. This makes me wonder what would happen if a folder were somehow deleted while the files within it were not. Is it possible for files or data to be created or accessed outside of the directory tree?

Comment: It depends upon the file system. Some file systems do no require files to be in a directory tree.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not specify which file system or operating system we target, this question can only be answered very broadly.

In general, files *cannot* exist outside of the directory tree of any filesystem, because then they could not be considered a file in the first place.

This considered, it is of course possible that the **data** contained in one or more files is still present on a hard drive after a folder holding them was deleted. A delete option is almost always - for the sake of speed - implemented by simply cutting all links between the actual data of the file, and the filesystem.

Because of this, lost files can often still be recovered using the right tools.

Comment: I may have unknowingly used incorrect terminology. I think what I was actually wondering was whether operating systems would let me write or access _data_ outside of the directory tree.

Comment: Operating systems usually do not permit this to userspace applications (unless you count the unnamed files user3188346 mentioned in his answer). Reading or writing data outside of a filesystem would mean programming on a device driver level, interfacing between the operating system and raw hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. As long as there is a process that has a valid file descriptor for that file, linux will not destroy it. Even if the file is removed from it's directory. It's called unnamed file.

From `The Linux Programming Interface - A Linux and UNIX System Programming Handbook, p.346` :

> An open file is deleted only when all file descriptors are closed
>   In addition to maintaining a link count for each i-node, the kernel also counts open
>   file descriptions for the file (see Figure 5-2, on page 95). If the last link to a file is
>   removed and any processes hold open descriptors referring to the file, the file
>   won’t actually be deleted until all of the descriptors are closed. This is a useful fea-
>   ture, because it permits us to unlink a file without needing to worry about whether
>   some other process has it open. (However, we can’t reattach a name to an open file
>   whose link count has fallen to 0.) In addition, we can perform tricks such as creat-
>   ing and opening a temporary file, unlinking it immediately, and then continuing to
>   use it within our program, relying on the fact that the file is destroyed only when
>   we close the file descriptor—either explicitly, or implicitly when the program exits.

Recently linux provides the possibility to open such descriptor without adding it to any directory. (see [O_TMPFILE](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html))